# Unable to move elements on a desktop using selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Hi Experts( I am just a learner),

I am automating a website using selenium C# on Visual Studio Express and Chrome Driver. The scenario is simple, like our windows desktop you can move icons anywhere, likewise the website I am automating has a desktop where I need to move to location A and B wherever I wanted to in that desktop area.

So far, I have tried MoveToElement(Element, Xoffset, Yoffset) but it doesn't seem to move.

Any ideas will be appreciated.
My script is below, and it is just based on moving element A to new location on same desktop.

```
       dragDrop.ClickAndHold(ElementA).MoveToElement(ElementA,100,200).Release(ElementA).Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use link for something like Body as ElementA in:

```
MoveToElement(Driver.FindElement(By.Id("body")),100,200)
```

Offset will be calculated inside the element provided. 
It looks little bit strange when you move element to itself:)